# Automated test runs with Altera Quartus

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, fpga, intel-fpga

I have an FPGA design in QuartusII, and a continuous integration server with some spare capacity.

Now I'd like to build a testsuite for my FPGA design, where input signals are generated by dedicated components, and the output signals checked against expected behaviour.

Is there a way to run the simulation non-interactively from a batch file, so that warnings can be collected in a log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ModelSim, you can certainly run simulation from the command-line. Some instructions are available from Altera [here](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii53001.pdf); you can probably get more instructions directly from [Mentor Graphics](http://www.mentor.com/products/fv/modelsim/).